# IO consuming with FP-TS

Tags: fp-ts

What is the idiomatic fp alternative of `forEach` part in this code

```ts
const ios: IO<void>[] = [...]
ios.forEach(io => io());
```

?

There are some docs which use `sequence_` from `Foldable` but it is no longer available in fp-ts@2.0.3.

**EDIT:**

The best I could do is

```ts
import { array } from 'fp-ts/lib/Array';

array.sequence(io)(ios)();
```

but `sequence` collects the results and I do not really have anything to do with `void[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing. The following seems to work.

```ts
import { IO, io } from 'fp-ts/lib/IO';
import { traverse_ } from 'fp-ts/lib/Foldable';
import { array } from 'fp-ts/lib/Array';
import { identity } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';
import { log } from 'fp-ts/lib/Console';

const actions: Array<IO<void>> = [log('hello'), log('world')];
const action: IO<void> = traverse_(io,array)(actions,identity);
```

Comment: So basically `sequence_` is `sg => xs => traverse_(sg, array)(xs, identity)`. Good to know.